# Not able to authorize GeoServer with LDAP groups

Tags: geoserver

I'm using GeoServer 2.8.5 and having problems authorizing using LDAP groups.
The authenticating works fine as I can logon with my LDAP users.
But if I try to Preview a layer which is only authorized for the according group I get the error:

> Cannot [Store name] with the current privileges, The server understood
>   the request but refuses to authorize it. Http status 403 Forbidden.

If I try the above with the local admin or a local user with the correct rights it works fine.
My LDAP settings (it is a test) are:

```
Server URL: ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389
TLS: [Not checked]
User lookup pattern: uid={0}, dc=example,dc=com
Filter used to lookup user: [empty]
Format used for user login name: [empty]
Use LDAP groups for authorization: [checked]
```

And the rest empty

In the role service section I have:

```
Server URL: ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389
TLS: [Not checked]
Group search base : dc=example,dc=com
Group user membership search filter: (&(objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)(uniquemember=*))
All groups search filter: (objectclass=groupOfUniqueNames)
Filter used to search users: (objectclass=person)
Authenticate to extract roles: [Checked]
Username: cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com
```

(it is een test server)

I am able to see the roles provide by LDAP.